# how to go next activity after interstitial ads closed Instead of same activity?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I want to  go next activity after interstitial ad closed instead of remaining on the same activity.

I have a `HomeActivity` and added interstitial ad on cardView.
after click card it show interstitial ad and when I closed ad it remains on the same activity. (I want to go second activity after ad is closed)

```
private void loadInterstitialads() {
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interad));
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Interstitial dismissed callback
            final Handler handle = new Handler();
            handle.postDelayed(() -> {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

            }, 10000000);
            // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
        }
    });
    }

    public void classClick(View view) {
        Intent i=new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SubCategoryActivity.class);

    if (view.getId()==R.id.india) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "india");

    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.world) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "world");

    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.geo) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "geo");

    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.history) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "history");

    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.chemistry) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "chemistry");

    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.bio) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "bio");

    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.sports) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "sports");

    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.economy) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "economy");

    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.physics) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "physics");

    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.politics) {
        i.putExtra("Category", "politics");
    }
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: so, why not add code inside `onAdClosed` to move to a new activity ? won't creating a new intent and starting it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your onAdClosed() method, hope it will be work

```
 mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Interstitial dismissed callback
           
             classClick(pass here your view);
        }
    });
```